# Ler um arquivo e transferir para um vetor

Tags: c

No caso, o que teria no arquivo seria tipo assim:

Baidu 12

Whastapp 53

.
.
.

e assim por diante, seria o nome do "app", e o numero q seria o tamanho do "app",
Mas nao to conseguindo ler nem uma palavra completa, e ainda queria poder separar o nome e o tamanho na info[].nome e info[].tam.

O que fiz até agora foi basicamente isso, claro fiz alguns outros testes, mas nenhum mostrou resultado:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
typedef struct app
{
char nome;
int tam;
} dados;
void trans (dados inf[6], FILE *Apps);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
FILE *App = fopen("App.txt", "r");
if (App == NULL)
{
    printf("ERRO! O arquivo não foi aberto!\n");
}
dados info[6];
trans(info, App);
printf("%c", info[0].nome);
return 0;
}

void trans (dados inf[6], FILE *Apps)
{
int i = 0, j=0;
char caracter, data[4];

while((caracter= fgetc(Apps))!='\n')
{
    data[j]= caracter;
    j++;
    if(j>3)
        break;
}
inf[i].nome=data;
```

}

Comment: Com "char nome;" você está definindo a variável nome como tendo um único caractere. Estude como definir uma string em C (array de caracteres com o terminador '\0'). Para atribuir uma string a outra em C utiliza-se a função strcpy de <string.h>.

Comment: acabei tendo uns erros bestas, tava um tempo sem ver C, mas arrumei o código ja